# What's wrong with the switch-case statement?

Tags: java, android

I do not why eclipse markes the `switch-case` statement with red squiggle, an says `Syntax error on token "{", SwitchLabels expected after this token` I tried both of the below posted code and i receive the same complain.

***Code_1***

```
switch (Test.h1.size()) {
    int size = Test.h1.size();

    case 1:
        break;

    case 2:
        break;
    }
```

***Code_2***

```
switch (Test.h1.size()) {
    int size = Test.h1.size();

    case size == 1:
        break;

    case size == 2:
    for (int i=1; i<=Test.h1.size()-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<=Test.h1.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println( Test.h1.get(i)+"+"+Test.h1.get(j)+"= "+((Test.h1.get(i))+(Test.h1.get(j))) );
        }
    }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you switch one variable and then make your cases correspond to another?

Comment: you're trying to execute code inside your switch, OUTSIDE of a case. move the `int size` bit to BEFORE the `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your code needs to be in cases. Did you read the docs? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Try this:

```
int size = Test.h1.size();

switch (size) {
    case 1:
        break;

    case 2:
        ....;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem in code 1 you only have to remove the line `int size = Test.h1.size();`.

For code 2 you should know, that in Java you cannot use boolean expressions in switch cases.